# mongodb aggregation to report on completeness

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I need to provide a report on data completeness for a collection of about 30M documents in a mongo collection. For example, given documents that look like this:

```
{
  _id: 1234567890AA,
  name: 'Betty Smith',
  demographics: {
    gender: 'F',
  },
  location: {
    country: 'Canada',
  },
}
```

I need to group by country and show the number of documents in that country along with the number of documents where `demographics.gender` has any non-null, non-undefined value.

What I'm trying is to add a `hasGender` field through the `$set` pipeline operation, then count it in `$group`:

```
db.cases.aggregate([
  {$set: { hasGender: { $cond: [ { $eq: { '$demographics.gender': null}}, 0, 1] }}},
  {$group: { _id: '$location.country', count: { $sum: 1}, gender: { $sum: '$hasGender' }} }
]);
```

So my expected outcome is an iteration of objects that look like this:

```
{
  _id: 'Canada',
  count: 126478,
  gender: 93647,
}
```

However mongo rejects my aggregation with the error `Unrecognized expression '$demographics.gender'`. If I remove the dollar sign, then it has the error `FieldPath field names may not contain '.'.`, which means it *does* think I'm writing a field path and field paths *can* contain $ AFAIK.

What is the correct syntax for this operation?

Comment: you need to correct the syntax of [$eq](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/eq/) in condition, its aggregation operator condition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mixed [$eq(aggregation)](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/eq/) with [$eq](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/eq/)

Consider these document:

```
[
   {
      name: 'Betty Smith',
      demographics: { gender: 'F' },
      location: { country: 'Canada' }
   },
   {
      name: 'Betty Smith',
      demographics: {},
      location: { country: 'Canada' }
   },
   {
      name: 'Betty Smith',
      location: { country: 'Canada' }
   },
   {
      name: 'Betty Smith',
      demographics: { gender: null },
      location: { country: 'Canada' }
   },
]
```

Depending on your requirements you would need on of these conditions:

```
db.cases.aggregate([
   { $project: { demographics: 1 } },
   { $set: { hasGender_1: { $cond: [{ $eq: ['$demographics.gender', null] }, 0, 1] } } },
   { $set: { hasGender_2: { $cond: [{ $eq: ['$demographics.gender', undefined] }, 0, 1] } } },
   { $set: { hasGender_3: { $cond: [{ $eq: [{ $type: '$demographics.gender' }, "string"] }, 1, 0] } } },
]);


{ 
    "demographics" : { "gender" : "F" }, 
    "hasGender_1" : 1.0, 
    "hasGender_2" : 1.0, 
    "hasGender_3" : 1.0
},
{ 
    "demographics" : { }, 
    "hasGender_1" : 1.0, 
    "hasGender_2" : 0.0, 
    "hasGender_3" : 0.0
},
{ 
    "hasGender_1" : 1.0, 
    "hasGender_2" : 0.0, 
    "hasGender_3" : 0.0
},
{ 
    "demographics" : { "gender" : null }, 
    "hasGender_1" : 0.0, 
    "hasGender_2" : 1.0, 
    "hasGender_3" : 0.0
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`$cond` needs to be an array.

Syntax:
`{ $cond: [ <boolean-expression>, <true-case>, <false-case> ] }`

This must be your condition :

```
$cond: [{$eq: ['$demographics.gender', null]}, 0, 1]
```

Refer to mongodb docs [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/)